# Ask for appraisal

Tags: communication, management, appraisal

I have been working in a small company for almost 2 years, but it seems that I still could not request for any appraisal from my direct manager. So how should I go about that?

Is it this company got a problem or I am the one that has a problem? I have asked my direct manager a few times but he asked me to ask higher management.

Comment: If your manager redirects you to upper management, you should go ask them, but that does seem like either bad management or... well, bad management.

Comment: sounds like a supervisor rather than a manager

Answer (score 2):

You need to follow instructions and ask higher management.

Your direct superior would normally be the person who does your appraisal, but may not have the authority or have other reasons for not doing so, in any case he/she has already told you what to do.

In many jobs your direct superior is a foreman or supervisor who isn't responsible for many admin or management type roles although they may have 'manager' in their job title eg,. floor manager, line manager etc,..

Comment: Thanks for the comment. Yes I think I should approach the higher management.

Answer (score 0):

Why do you feel you need an appraisal? I've worked at companies which insist on appraisals every year, but it's just to make the HR team happy; nothing changes. I've worked at companies where my manager said "I'll tick the boxes for HR, but really - we work closely enough together that we shouldn't need this".

If your supervisor tells you to go higher in the chain to get an answer to your question, you should do exactly that.

Comment: thanks for the comment. Well there is no changes to my designation. Or no traces on my performance. How do I gauge myself? And yes will proceed to the higher mgmt for the accurate answer.